# How cassandra key caches works when same key is exists in more than one sstables?

Tags: caching, cassandra

1) As per datastax key cache stores the primary key index for rowkey.

2) In our case we have enough memory allocated for key cache and same key is present in multiple sstables with diffrent columns.

3) If no of calls are made to access all these same key from multiple sstables then how indexes are stored in key cache? will it store indexes for all the sstables OR just for the last sstable from which key is accessed recently?

Comment: I have updated the answer properly. Plz let me know if it is clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Doc](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/maximizing-cache-benefit-with-cassandra)

> The key cache holds the location of keys in memory on a per-column
>   family basis.

<strike>Key cache serves as an index for a key in all sstables it is present.</strike>

Key cache is maintained per sstable. Hence key cache can save one disk seek per SSTable [minimum]. Every key lookup ends up hitting atleast the bloom filter of all sstable. On success key cache is verified just to skip the sstable index [pointers to key sample @ interval of 127 by default] lookup.

Read Path of cassandra goes like this

**Memtable -> Row Cache (Off heap) ->  Bloom filter -> Key cache -> SSTable Index [if miss]** -> *Disk*

Everything in bold means they are maintained in memory (either in heap or off heap). Hence they don't add up to disk seek

Every sstable should be maintaining its own key cache. [Souce](http://www.slideshare.net/aaronmorton/cassandra-does-what-code-mania-2012) from slide no 101 and [Source2](http://www.slideshare.net/acunu/cassandra-eu-2012-storage-internals-by-nicolas-favrefelix) from slide no 23

Incase of key cache miss, sstable index is used - that will give the clue over which 128th range might the key lie. From then disk seek for key starts [can be 1 to many].

I'll update the answer once again if I get any clue on how does cassandra descide on key cache size of every sstable may be [key_cache_conf/no_of_sstables]?

Comment: @samarth what do u mean by a verifiable source? I have already mentioned the doc resource in the answer. Even `key cache can save one disk seek per SSTable` this was from the doc

Comment: I want source for your statment "Key cache serves as an index for a key in all sstables it is present" any links or documentation or source code will be very helpful.

Comment: @samarth What does `key cache can save one disk seek per SSTable` mean to you? If it is the other way you think they would have clearly mentioned `key cache can save one disk seek` instead per sstable. Then it is upto you. You can keep searching :) And we use key cache in our cassandra cluster after understanding so :)

Comment: @samarth have added one more ref

Comment: I am little bit confuse about the read flow.Could you explain it in your answer? Like if the bloom filter comes before cache or its other way around?

Comment: source2 http://goo.gl/Gop6P5 slides 39-44 says  memtable->row_cache->bloom_filter->key_cache->sstable_index which are all in jvm (row cache is off-heap) then it fetches the values from sstable file which is `mmap`-ed into the process address space so the OS can cache pages of the file in ram. There is a bloom filter per sstable file which tells you if the file doesn't contain the key so you don't check its cache or index. sstables are created by writes and compaction so there are many possibly huge and the bloom filters reduce the set you have to check to reconstruct the latest row value.